# Self reference is a pain

Tags: english, formation-of-numbers

How many letters do the answer of this puzzle contain?

NB: This came across while web surfing. I don't claim any ownership rights.

Answer (score 5):

May be

> four

Logic

> None of the other digits expressed in words have appropriate word-length

Comment: Interesting alternate answer would be 0.

Comment: That is a good interesting deviation! Kudos

Answer (score 5):

The answer contains thirty letters

Comment: any hint as to why?

Comment: Just count the letters...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> fourteen plus three

Which contains exactly

> 17 letters

Comment: And `seven plus seven`, `fifteen times one`, `one followed by six`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 4 (Four)

Reason

> it is the only number that contains the same number of letters to spell it. This speaks to the title, as it is self referential.

Answer (score 2):

It is

> 21, as the number of letters in

the answer of this puzzle

> is 21.